# Align "add to cart" buttons in a straight line in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, height, product

Please guide me to bring all the "add to basket buttons" in straight line. Currently they are not in proportion.

If anyone can help me with a quick code?

[image: screen shot of shop the page]

How to align "add to cart" buttons in a straight line in WooCommerce shop page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align box items so buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221064/how-to-align-box-items-so-buttons)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The products names (or titles) are embedded in a  tag this way:

```
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Product title</h2>
```

So you need to define a `min-height` css rule for that class choosing the **biggest** height of your product names. So if the biggest product name height is 96 pixels, you will set your rule this way *(for example)*:

```css
.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    min-height: 100px;
    /* OR
    min-height: 100px !important; */
}
```

You should add this css rule to the style.css file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox and then the magic `margin-top: auto` on the button. You can ignore the `display: grid` on the `.items` container. It's just for the columns.

```css
.items{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}
.item{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item button{
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. </p>
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur  </p>
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
    <button>Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

More information about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/