# How do I align Gutenberg add-to-cart buttons horizontally on a WooCommerce product category page?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

**Environment:** Using Twenty Three theme FSE & WooCommerce and the Products (Beta) Gutenberg block to display product categories. No horizontal tool exists to align these buttons horizontally that I can find so I'm looking for a css solution. Changing text length isn't an option and also not optimal.

**Example of problem:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771884/align-add-to-cart-buttons-in-a-straight-line-in-woocommerce-shop-page/45773629#45773629) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Using `position: relative;` on the grey square and

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

on the buttons.

### Solution 2

*(not so nice)*

Using

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

on the grey square and putting `<span style="flex: 1;">` before the button.